# Is there any way to load Direct Map View ,hiding default North America loading?

Tags: google-maps, xcode4.2

I have made an GPS Location based Mapkit application for a store where it has four locations at the table view and when the user selects any one of them then it navigates to MapView and all the stuff gets loaded but my problem is that at the loading time it is showing North America Map after loading completes i am getting the required map view.I need either activity indicator or blank grey map screen to be display at the loading time.
[image: map view at the loading time]
[image: after loading gets completed]

i am calling the mapview programatically where my coding is

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 372.0f)];
self.view = contentView;
[contentView release];

routeMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:contentView.frame];
routeMapView.delegate = self;
routeMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[contentView addSubview:routeMapView];
[routeMapView release];

routeOverlayView = [[UICRouteOverlayMapView alloc] initWithMapView:routeMapView];
UIBarButtonItem *space = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *currentLocationButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reticle.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(moveToCurrentLocation:)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *routesButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showRouteListView:)] autorelease];
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentLocationButton, space, /*mapPinButton,*/ routesButton, nil];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the solution for my question,
first defining a local region co-ordinate like this

```
MKCoordinateRegion region={{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
```

then defining animation for changes made over it,

```
[routeMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

then

```
activityIndicator =[[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]autorelease];
activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
activityIndicator.center=self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

if([UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES)
{

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

}
```

then declaring [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; at the delegate function where all the end of the operation takes place.